# prevent redirection on submit to form

Tags: ajax, post

I have the following code I am using to submit my form to a processing script. the form gets submitted but I am getting redirected to the response html from the server. I want to stay on the same page and run the callback function inside success:

the response header is sending
location:http://url-I-am-Redirected-to-and-don't-want-to-be.html

I am working with third party and have no control over the server side code I am submitting to.

```
  $('#go').click (function () {

        $.ajax ( {
        type: 'POST',   
        data: $('#newsletter form').serialize(),
        url: $('#newsletter').attr('action'),
        success: function(){
        $('#image_container').hide (1000,

       );
      }
     });

    }
```

Comment: Are you missing a trailing ')' at the end of the code snippet?

Comment: Also the hide call is missing an ending parenthesis, the ending ajax block has the parenthesis and curly mixed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the click block add

```
return false
```

Comment: @Daedalus do my additional comments please you?

Comment: It isn't about pleasing me, it's about helping the OP, but sure.