# HTML form post with custom redirection

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I was reading the thread [prevent redirection on submit to form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131802/prevent-redirection-on-submit-to-form), and I have a question.
Is possible have a HTML form like:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="/SaveDate" <!-- some other properties --> >
<input type="text" name="username" />
<input type="upload" name="upload" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But, when the method `SaveData` (POST) is executed, only refresh the page? (using javascript)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found another method that could be used, its kinda a hidden Iframe - try this, works for me.

CSS
   `<style>
    .hide { position:absolute; top:-1px; left:-1px; width:1px; height:1px; }
    </style>`

HTML
    `<iframe name="hiddenFrame" class="hide"></iframe>`

```
`<form method="POST" action="/SaveDate" target="hiddenFrame"> <!-- some other properties --> >
<input type="text" name="username" />
<input type="upload" name="upload" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>`
```

Try - `<INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="history.go(0)" VALUE="Refresh">` does that help ?

Comment: Please edit your post to provide an explanation of what the code does and how it will solve the OP's problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Insead of using **form post method**

Use jquery

```
 $.post( "test.html", function( data ) {
 $( ".idofelement" ).html( data );
 });
```